# Is DJI SDK communicate with MAVLink protocol?

Tags: ios, dronekit, dji-sdk, mavlink

I am making an app for Auto Boat system and as I read the Doc of Drone Kit API . This API is not for iOS. I have searched for another one which is DJI SDK .

I am using pixhawk device for flight controller and it listen MAVLink protocol .

I just want to know that is DJI able communicate with MAVLink protocol .

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 4):

DJI SDK does not support MAVlink. Besides DJI SDK works only with DJI Flightcontrollers.

Comment: Have you  worked on DJI .  Thanks for quick reply  @ lchaival

Answer (score 3):

The DJI SDK only works with DJI flight controllers. They most likely have their own over-the-air protocol that differs from MAVLink.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, your best bet is to use the MAVLink code generator to generate code for Objective-C or Swift. This is available here: https://github.com/mavlink/mavlink

That being said, it doesn't generate an easy to use SDK like the DJI SDK. You are going to need to spend a lot of time reading the documentation for MAVLink in order to know what messages to send, and when to send them. I'd advise you to take a look at the source code for one of the open source ground control stations that works with it such as this one: https://github.com/mavlink/qgroundcontrol

Answer (score 1):

The only exception as I know is the Matrice series drone. Which is quite extendable and compatible with an on-board framework that can read MAVLink:

https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/github-platform-docs/ROS_Example/ros_dji2mav_0.2.1_package.html

The document is pretty new so it should work by now. But Matrice series drones are not cheap.